# Force.com IDE plugin for auto creating a skeletal structure for a doc comment filled with some content

Tags: ide

I'm searching for a way of typing auto doc comments for the Force.com IDE. For example, when using Netbeans for creating Javadoc Stubs:

> Place the cursor above a method or a class that has no Javadoc, type
>   "/**", and press Enter. The IDE creates a skeletal structure for a
>   Javadoc comment filled with some content.

If someone know of a way of doing this, as Apex is close to Java, I was sure such a feature will be implemented with the Force.com IDE, but was disappointed to learn the opposite.

I know you can generate Documentation of a documented Apex code with apexDoc and Doxygen, but I'm looking for a way to easily document\comment the code.

Thanks.

Comment: With many orders of magnitude fewer Apex developers than Java developers, and Salesforce not even willing to share the grammar of their language with outside parties, don't be surprised that the development tools are not as good. On the subject of documenting code, one viewpoint is that well named and designed classes and methods need little further documentation. What problem are you aiming to solve with Javadoc-style documentation?

Comment: Only speed up document of code, and make it modular for all programmers.

Comment: Modern IDEs provide documentation snippets and tools. Checkout my tool, SfApexDoc for generating HTML documentation: http://force-code.com/sfapexdoc/

Comment: @SteveCox it was asked long time ago, today you have IntelliJ with Illuminated Cloud plugin and VS code with Salesforce official plugin both support documentation and much more...